# Django 2.2: How can I Modify a Specific Page in the Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

I am having some real trouble finding a definitive, descriptive answer to my question.

**Situation**

I need to add a URL/Link to a specific page in my Django Admin.

**Why I am stuck / Where I need help**

I can't quite figure out how to modify a specific page in the Django Admin. Once I figure out how to modify that specific page, I then need to modify a specific `div` on that page to insert what I am looking to insert (an `anchor` tag styled like a button).

**Where I am**

What I need to do is different than what I've done in the past. I have modified the admin backend before, but very slightly... I added a banner to my admin site to show me whether I am in a production environment or development environment like this:
[image: Added Banner]

I did that by doing this:

```
# templates/admin/base_site.html

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block extrastyle %}

<style type="text/css">
    body:before {
        display: block;
        line-height: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: white;
        content: "{{ ENVIRONMENT_NAME }}";
        background-color: {{ ENVIRONMENT_COLOR }};
    }
</style>

{% endblock %}
```

-

```
# project/context_processor.py

from django.conf import settings

def from_settings(request):
    return {
        'ENVIRONMENT_NAME': settings.ENVIRONMENT_NAME,
        'ENVIRONMENT_COLOR': settings.ENVIRONMENT_COLOR,
    }
```

-

```
# settings/base.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'wabiclean.context_processors.from_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I need to edit just 1 specific page and that is what I am really having a hard time with.